# Attempt to present VC2 on VC1 which is already presenting

Tags: ios, swift

Presently at a lost for why I am receiving the message of Attempt to present VC2 on VC1 which is already presenting when the VC1 does both the presenting and dismissing of the VC2. There are a few other questions and a lot of examples and I've not been able to resolve it from looking through them.

VC2 is called RoadwaysViewController and is opened as a modal. The only catch I see is that VC2 is used by 2 other VC. Things work great for awhile and then the problem arises when I've moved back and forth from VC to VC after awhile and in each I've used VC2. VC2 was intended to be used in multiple places since the data is the same for all.

Presenting and dismissing are both done from VC1.

class level variable

```
var roadwaysViewController = RoadwaysViewController()
```

Here is how it is presented

```
func roadwayTapped(){
    roadwaysViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RoadwayModal") as! RoadwaysViewController
    roadwaysViewController.delegate = self
    self.present(self.roadwaysViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Here is how it is dismissed on VC1 the callback from the delegate.

```
func sendValue(value: Int, name:  String) {
    roadwaysViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        if value == 999 {
            return
        }
        self.groupId = value
        self.roadName.text = name
        self.setupTableData()
    })
}
```

I've tried checking to see if VC2 is presenting and then did dismiss. Tried this in the function that does the presenting, viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear.

I understand you can't have 2 VC presented at the same time but why it isn't getting properly dismissed I'm struggling to understand why. I don't believe I want to dismiss the parent and then show the child since the child is a modal.

Any help, ideas or suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: It's strange to hold onto a view controller for repeated presenting. It's not expensive to create new view controllers; I would try doing away with the controller variable and create a new one when you're ready to present.

Comment: I see what you are saying but I don't see how that would work since the present and dismiss are different functions. Do you instantiate it again in the  dismiss function, the one the delegate returns, sendValue?

Comment: The recommended way of dismissing is to call `dismiss` on the _presenter_, not the presented controller. If you just call dismiss on VC1, it should dismiss VC2: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismissviewcontrolleranimated

Comment: Right, I'm already doing that in the call back function, sendValue, which is on VC1 and is called from VC2